# Snowflake Automation Tasks in your current or previous organization

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Just curious to know the automations you have done in your snowflake job ( may be in your current organization or previous one ).

Automations or BI Related tasks.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can automate almost anything. I have faced such tasks as:

- orchestration with ETL/ELT processes
- copying/moving files on External Stage
- direct loading of data from e-mail messages
- alarms and automatic notifications about Snowflake charge or costs
- automation of granting RBAC permissions
- creating new copies of environments
- database replication
- data backup on AWS S3 (customer requirement)
- CI/CD processes
- and much much more

If you are looking for a good automation tool, I strongly recommend **AutomateNOW!**.

AutomateNOW! enables you natively communicate with Snowflake. Thanks to that you can manage and monitor Snowflake processes such as stored procedures, queries, DMLs and so on. AutomateNOW! is also useful to reduce the cost of Snowflake usage because in a dynamic manner it is able to decide what size of Data Warehouse should be launched and once the process is finished it can dynamically resize the warehouse or make it suspended. In addition the output of the Explain Plan of SF queries can be used and parsed on the  fly in order to manage workload of Snowflake. I see the enormous potential when Snowflake is one of the components of a multi technology ecosystem and it is needed  to manage the whole process or chain  of the process.

Tool link: [AutomateNOW!](https://infinitedata.com)

Examples of AutomateNOW! screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks ,i will try to write a procedure to automate stuffs like this